# Flash is installed but all flash embeds are replaced with blue i information icon

Tags: firefox, flash, flash-player

Flash is installed but all flash embeds are replaced with blue i information icon. And I am using a web browser called [Basilisk](http://basilisk-browser.org) that supports flash. Is a windows update by microsoft blocking the flash player from running?

Why is this happening?

[image: flash version]

[image: flash content replaced with blue i information icon]